# Trying to understand a ML problem

Tags: multiple-regression

I feel bad asking for help without a specific understanding.

My dataset is to understand how medication(n=10) and genome (in the form of mutations, n=40)affects the subject's depression (in the form of a HAMD score)
My dataset is in the form of n patients where the patient has x number of biweekly records. Each record states the medication the patient has taken for that time period and the HAMD score. The data also contains the mutations that the patient has from a list of 40 possible mutations.

{id:00001, mutations:[A,B,C], report:[{number:1, medication:cymbalta, score:15},{number:2, medication:cymbalta, score:12}}

What I am trying to find out is the impact that each mutation/medication pair has on the HAMD score.

I understand that to take interactions into consideration I have to use polynomial features BUT I am unsure on how to interpret the results of how Drug1:Mutatuion1 affects the HAMD score of the patient.

I hope that I have not oversimplified the problem to the point of it being under-informative.

Thanks !

Edit: Added more details for clarity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added extra content for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding what worked for me

1. I first defined the independent and dependant variables:

```
    x = df4.drop(['none','id','date','hamd','b_hamd','hamd_diff'], axis=1)
    y = df4['hamd_diff']
```

2. I then used sklearn's PolynomialFeatures to get the interaction features and transformed them. Finally called the model

```
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False, interaction_only=True)
    data = poly.fit_transform(x)
    regr = ElasticNetCV(cv=5, random_state=0)
    regr.fit(data, y)
    score = (regr.coef_.tolist())
```

3. I created the composite features of interest and used the `get_feature_names_out()` method to extract the coefficients that I was interested in

```
    poly_features_q7 = []
    for x in mutation_list:
        for y in med_list:
            pair = x+' '+y
            poly_features_q7.append(pair)
    coef = []
    for f,s in zip(poly.get_feature_names_out(),score):
        if f in poly_features_q7:
            print(s)
            coef.append(s)
```